# How to put a detail view in a bootstrap grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a detail view between rows in my web application.
I am using Bootstrap and some Frontend Rendering.

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    ...
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    ...
</div>
etc...
```

I am basically looking for some way to do this in bootstrap or some library that does it. The closest example I could find is in the newest itunes version, I've attached a screenshot for that.

[image: Example of Detail View]

**Edit:**

**What I have tried / thought of:**

1. Put the detail view as an absolutely positioned div inside the tile and give the tile a margin-bottom.

This didn't work out since the layout simply breaks. To make this work, you would have to give all elements in the row a margin-bottom.

2. Put a set of tiles into a row-div and just insert the detail div after that specific row.

This will either break every responsive feature or require a lot of javascript to somehow dynamically put the divs into rows.

I am basically looking for a library / css hack that makes me able to do this without writing a whole lot of javascript.

Comment: I can't come up with a simple solution. Layouts like this have alrdy been done before so there must be something out there :)

Comment: I don't see any angular code here at all.  It's not clear what exactly your issue is, but angular doesn't normally have anything to do with page layouts.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'details' row, you'd probable just need to use:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    ...
</div>
```

That would force it to span the full width regardless of the screen size.  So your 3 rows would look like:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    ...
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I want to be able to open a detail view dynamically under any grid element. There is no angular code because I haven't posted much of my actual code. I just stated I use angular in case somebody can come up with a nifty little directive I could just use.

Comment: @JochenNiebuhr what exactly have you tried? right now you don't exactly have a question, rather you have a statement of the technology you are using and an end result.  This isn't a software writing service;  we need to know what you are having trouble with, and just saying "I hope someone can make a directive for me" isn't a problem, it's a demand, which is unlikely to get a response.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood original question.  You have lots of options, one way would be to use ng-click on each "cell" to set a variable in your controller, then show/hide the correct full-width panel based on the value of 'currentCell'.  For example <div class="col-sm-4" ng-click="currentCell = 1">, and then have panels set up like <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="currentCell == 1">.  That would also require some Angular code like a controller to make it work.